Issue with Trigger.oldMap and Trigger.newMap not showing correct old value in after update trigger
I have an after update trigger on a managed package object (TasksObject__c). In this trigger, I need to check the old value of the Status__c field. When I update the Status__c field from 'In Progress' to 'Completed', both Trigger.oldMap and Trigger.newMap are showing 'Completed'. I expect Trigger.oldMap to show the previous value ('In Progress') but it doesn't seem to.
Trigger Code:
trigger TaskTrigger on TasksObject__c(after update) {
    for (Tasks__c tsk : Trigger.new) {  
        System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.old is: ' + Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status__c);
        System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.new is: ' + Trigger.newMap.get(tsk.Id).Status__c);
    }
}

Current Output:
***SFDC: Trigger.old is: Completed
***SFDC: Trigger.new is: Completed

I was expecting:
***SFDC: Trigger.old is: In Progress
***SFDC: Trigger.new is: Completed

Has anyone experienced this issue with managed package objects or have any insights into why this might be happening? Any help would be appreciated!

Do you have checked the consideration of the order of execution? Also, see this article may help you.

This sounds like you used an "AI" to write the question (which probably has similar issues as using "AI" to write answers). Is this your actual code? If not, you should [edit] your question to provide the actual code you have that's experiencing the issue.

@DerekF good catch. Unless OP copied the actual code but made a mistake while trying to sanitize to be able to post here.

@derek it was rephrased using AI. I have updated it. This is actual code which is causing issue.

@tushar I have also tried deactivating flows, workflows. Still same issue.
